# MySQL Parsing JSON like values

Tags: mysql, json

I have a column.

multvalues with the following string.

{quantity: 50, cost: 0.675}, {quantity: 1, cost: 0.722}

I have tried JSON_EXTRACT, but the data is not quite formatted properly. What is another way to parse out this data? I am trying to get quantity and cost so that I can store it in another table. At minimum there is one quantity to cost value, at most there would be 3.

I figure I could use SUBSTRING_INDEX but figure there has to be a better approach.

Comment: *I have a column. multvalues with the following string* - it is not clear. Show your data as `CREATE TABLE` + `INSERT INTO` (3-5 rows) SQL code, and provide desired output for this data. Also specify precise MySQL version.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to avoid parsing at all, by normalizing your database. Use a second table with columns for `quantity` and `cost`. Store each of your tuples in separate rows.

```
CREATE TABLE my_second_table (
  ... define a primary key ...
  quantity INT NOT NULL,
  cost DECIMAL(9,3) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_second_table (quantity, cost) 
VALUES (50, 0.675), (1, 0.722);
```

Now you don't have to parse anything! You can add or delete or update tuples with ordinary SQL commands.

Using formatted data like you show is an example of the [Inner-Platform Effect antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect).

If you were to use formatted data, *at least use valid JSON,* so you have [builtin JSON functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/json-functions.html) to work with.

Using not-quite-JSON format means you have to develop your own solutions for tasks that are already coded for you!

This is like a carpenter who doesn't want to use nails, so they want to whittle iron bars down to nail-sized pieces and then hammer those into the wood.

Comment: I like the "Inner-Platform Effect"!